# Picture loaded from my server has wrong colors on iPad app

Tags: ios, image, ipad, colors, srgb

I am developing an iPad app which presents pictures from a photographer. Those photos are uploaded on a webserver, and served directly through the app, where they are downloaded and displayed using the method below :

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]){
    CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)url, NULL);
    CGImageRef cgImage = nil;
    if(source){
        cgImage = CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(source, 0, (CFDictionaryRef)dict);
    }

    UIImage *retImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];

    if(cgImage){
        CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    }
    if(source){
        CFRelease(source);
    }

    return retImage;
}
```

I can observe a serious change in the display of the photos' colours between the original picture (which is the same when displayed from the disk or from the web on my Mac and the photographer's Mac) and on the iPad (the result is wrong in the app and even in Safari).

After some search I found some posts explaining how iDevices do not use embedded color profile, so I found I was going this way. The photos are saved using the following info :

[image: colorspace: RGB, colorprofile: sRGB iec...]

I found out on some articles (for example [this link from imageoptim](https://imageoptim.com/color-profiles.html) or [analogsenses](http://www.analogsenses.com/2015/08/12/ios-and-color-management-how-to-export-jpeg-files-from-lightroom-for-mobile-viewing/)) that I should save the picture for device export by converting it to sRGB, without embedding the color profile, but I cant find out how could I do that ? Each time I tried (I don't have photoshop, so I used command line ImageMagick), the resulting picture has the following information, and is still not displayed correctly on my iPad (and any other iPads I've tested) :

[image: colorspace: RGB]

[Here is a example of a picture that do not display correctly on the iPhone or iPad, but does on the web](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/14165290/test-image.jpg)

I would like to transform it to display it correctly, any Idea would be really welcomed :)

[EDIT] I have succeeded to obtain a correct image using "save for web" options of photoshop using the following parameters : 
[image: ok photoshop export parameters]
But I'm still unable to apply those settings automatically to all my pictures.

Comment: color not changed,, just appearance change due to retina display of device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read an image, just use:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

As for the color profile issue, try the `sips` command-line tool to fix the image files. Something like:

```
mkdir converted
sips -m "/System/Library/ColorSync/Profiles/sRGB Profile.icc" *.JPG --out converted
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get first the color space through CGImage.

```
@property(nonatomic, readonly) CGImageRef CGImage

CGColorSpaceRef CGImageGetColorSpace (
   CGImageRef image
);
```

And depping of the colorSpace apply a format conversion. So to get the color space of an image, you'd do:

```
CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGImageGetColorSpace([myUIImage CGImage]);
```

*Note: make sure to follow the get/create/copy rules for CG objects.*

Color conversion to RGB8 (also can be applied to RGB16 or RGB32, changing the bits per component in the method `newBitmapRGBA8ContextFromImage`):

```
// Create a bitmap
unsigned char *bitmap = [ImageHelper convertUIImageToBitmapRGBA8:image];

    // Create a UIImage using the bitmap
UIImage *imageCopy = [ImageHelper convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage:bitmap withWidth:width withHeight:height];

    // Display the image copy on the GUI
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageCopy];
```

**ImageHelper.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>


@interface ImageHelper : NSObject {

}

/** Converts a UIImage to RGBA8 bitmap.
 @param image - a UIImage to be converted
 @return a RGBA8 bitmap, or NULL if any memory allocation issues. Cleanup memory with free() when done.
 */
+ (unsigned char *) convertUIImageToBitmapRGBA8:(UIImage *)image;

/** A helper routine used to convert a RGBA8 to UIImage
 @return a new context that is owned by the caller
 */
+ (CGContextRef) newBitmapRGBA8ContextFromImage:(CGImageRef)image;


/** Converts a RGBA8 bitmap to a UIImage. 
 @param buffer - the RGBA8 unsigned char * bitmap
 @param width - the number of pixels wide
 @param height - the number of pixels tall
 @return a UIImage that is autoreleased or nil if memory allocation issues
 */
+ (UIImage *) convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage:(unsigned char *)buffer 
    withWidth:(int)width
    withHeight:(int)height;

@end
```

**ImageHelper.m**

```
#import "ImageHelper.h"


@implementation ImageHelper


+ (unsigned char *) convertUIImageToBitmapRGBA8:(UIImage *) image {

    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    // Create a bitmap context to draw the uiimage into
    CGContextRef context = [self newBitmapRGBA8ContextFromImage:imageRef];

    if(!context) {
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

    // Draw image into the context to get the raw image data
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, imageRef);

    // Get a pointer to the data    
    unsigned char *bitmapData = (unsigned char *)CGBitmapContextGetData(context);

    // Copy the data and release the memory (return memory allocated with new)
    size_t bytesPerRow = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(context);
    size_t bufferLength = bytesPerRow * height;

    unsigned char *newBitmap = NULL;

    if(bitmapData) {
        newBitmap = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * bytesPerRow * height);

        if(newBitmap) { // Copy the data
            for(int i = 0; i < bufferLength; ++i) {
                newBitmap[i] = bitmapData[i];
            }
        }

        free(bitmapData);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error getting bitmap pixel data\n");
    }

    CGContextRelease(context);

    return newBitmap;   
}

+ (CGContextRef) newBitmapRGBA8ContextFromImage:(CGImageRef) image {
    CGContextRef context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    uint32_t *bitmapData;

    size_t bitsPerPixel = 32;
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bytesPerPixel = bitsPerPixel / bitsPerComponent;

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(image);

    size_t bytesPerRow = width * bytesPerPixel;
    size_t bufferLength = bytesPerRow * height;

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    if(!colorSpace) {
        NSLog(@"Error allocating color space RGB\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Allocate memory for image data
    bitmapData = (uint32_t *)malloc(bufferLength);

    if(!bitmapData) {
        NSLog(@"Error allocating memory for bitmap\n");
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        return NULL;
    }

    //Create bitmap context

    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData, 
            width, 
            height, 
            bitsPerComponent, 
            bytesPerRow, 
            colorSpace, 
            kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);    // RGBA
    if(!context) {
        free(bitmapData);
        NSLog(@"Bitmap context not created");
    }

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return context; 
}

+ (UIImage *) convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage:(unsigned char *) buffer 
        withWidth:(int) width
       withHeight:(int) height {


    size_t bufferLength = width * height * 4;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, bufferLength, NULL);
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bitsPerPixel = 32;
    size_t bytesPerRow = 4 * width;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    if(colorSpaceRef == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Error allocating color space");
        CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
        return nil;
    }

    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width, 
                height, 
                bitsPerComponent, 
                bitsPerPixel, 
                bytesPerRow, 
                colorSpaceRef, 
                bitmapInfo, 
                provider,   // data provider
                NULL,       // decode
                YES,            // should interpolate
                renderingIntent);

    uint32_t* pixels = (uint32_t*)malloc(bufferLength);

    if(pixels == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Error: Memory not allocated for bitmap");
        CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
        CGImageRelease(iref);       
        return nil;
    }

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, 
                 width, 
                 height, 
                 bitsPerComponent, 
                 bytesPerRow, 
                 colorSpaceRef, 
                 bitmapInfo); 

    if(context == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Error context not created");
        free(pixels);
    }

    UIImage *image = nil;
    if(context) {

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height), iref);

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

        // Support both iPad 3.2 and iPhone 4 Retina displays with the correct scale
        if([UIImage respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:)]) {
            float scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        } else {
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        }

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);   
        CGContextRelease(context);  
    }

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGImageRelease(iref);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

    if(pixels) {
        free(pixels);
    }   
    return image;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

@PhilippeAuriach
I think you might have problem with `[UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage]`, My suggestion is use `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path]` instead of above.

Below code might be help you.

```
if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[url path]]){
    //Provide image path here...
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];

    if(image){
        return image;
    }else{
       //Return default image
       return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried and it did not change anything, the image still have the same colors